# How To Subtract CBOT Grain Prices

Tags: vb.net

I had to calculate the difference between Chicago Board of Trade grain futures prices using VB.net and came up with the following (admittedly clunky) solution.  It's a *little* tricky because CBOT prices, as posted, mix octal and decimal numbers.  Anyway, here is my code for you to enjoy and tear apart:

```
   Public Function GrainSubtraction(ByVal numberOne As Double, ByVal numberTwo As Double) As Double

    ' This is a somewhat convoluted function to subtract CBOT grain prices ... but it seems to work
    ' It assumes the numbers have no decimals - that is, if the price of corn is $4.75 3/4 per bushel, this number is represented as 4756 where the last digit (6) represents 6/8

    ' Basically, we perform octal subtraction on the smallest unit digit and regular decimal subtraction on the remaining digits
    ' I use arrays to do this so I can isolate each digit - there is probably a more efficient way to do this, though - I'm not a quant

    Dim tempOne As Double = 0.0
    Dim tempTwo As Double = 0.0

    Dim inverted As Boolean = False 'Flags whether the second number is larger than the first
    Dim answer As Double = 0.0 ' This will be our ultimate response
    Dim multiplier As Double = 1.0

    ' Here, we compare the two numbers and invert them if the second number is largest then the first

    If numberOne = numberTwo Then Return 0.0

    If numberOne < numberTwo Then
        tempOne = numberTwo
        tempTwo = numberOne
        inverted = True
    Else
        tempOne = numberOne
        tempTwo = numberTwo
    End If

    Dim lengthOne = CStr(tempOne).Length ' How many digits in number one?
    Dim lengthTwo = CStr(tempTwo).Length

    Dim I As Integer = 0
    Dim errorFlag As Boolean = False 'Let's us know whether we hit an error with this number 

    Dim numberLength As Integer
    If lengthOne > lengthTwo Then numberLength = lengthOne Else numberLength = lengthTwo

    ' Create our array
    Dim numberOneArray(numberLength) As Integer
    Dim numberTwoArray(numberLength) As Integer
    Dim answerArray(numberLength) As Integer ' This will hold our answer as an array

    ' Set Array Values To Zero
    For I = 0 To numberLength - 1
        numberOneArray(I) = 0
        numberTwoArray(I) = 0
    Next

    For I = 0 To lengthOne - 1
        numberOneArray(I) = tempOne Mod 10
        tempOne = Int(tempOne / 10)
    Next

    For I = 0 To lengthTwo - 1
        numberTwoArray(I) = tempTwo Mod 10
        tempTwo = Int(tempTwo / 10)
    Next I

    ' This is where we do the actual analysis

    For I = 0 To numberLength - 1

        If I = 0 Then ' We're doing Octal subtraction here

            If numberOneArray(I) >= numberTwoArray(I) Then
                answerArray(I) = numberOneArray(I) - numberTwoArray(I)
            Else
                If I = numberLength Then
                    errorFlag = True
                Else
                    numberOneArray(I) = numberOneArray(I) + 8
                    numberOneArray(I + 1) = numberOneArray(I + 1) - 1
                    answerArray(I) = numberOneArray(I) - numberTwoArray(I)
                End If
            End If

        Else ' We're doing Decimal subtraction here

            If numberOneArray(I) >= numberTwoArray(I) Then
                answerArray(I) = numberOneArray(I) - numberTwoArray(I)
            Else
                If I = numberLength Then
                    errorFlag = True
                Else
                    numberOneArray(I) = numberOneArray(I) + 10
                    numberOneArray(I + 1) = numberOneArray(I + 1) - 1
                    answerArray(I) = numberOneArray(I) - numberTwoArray(I)
                End If
            End If

        End If

    Next

    multiplier = 1

    If errorFlag = True Then Return 0.0

    For I = 0 To numberLength - 1
        answer = answer + (answerArray(I) * multiplier)
        multiplier = multiplier * 10
    Next

    If inverted = True Then answer = -answer
    Return answer

End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

The following will shorten your code considerably:

```
Public Function GrainSubtraction(ByVal numberOne As Double, ByVal numberTwo As Double) As Double
    Dim Dec1 As Integer = CInt(Int(numberOne / 10.0))
    Dim Oct1 As Integer = CInt(numberOne - (Dec1 * 10))
    Dim Dec2 As Integer = CInt(Int(numberTwo / 10))
    Dim Oct2 As Integer = CInt(numberTwo - (Dec2 * 10))
    Dim ResultDec, ResultOct As Integer
    If Oct1 < Oct2 Then
        Dec1 -= 1
        ResultOct = CInt(7 - (Oct2 - Oct1))
    Else
        ResultOct = CInt(Oct1 - Oct2)
    End If
    ResultDec = CInt(Dec1 - Dec2)
    Return CDbl((Math.Abs(ResultDec * 10) + ResultOct) * Math.Sign(ResultDec))
End Function
```

This does simple octal subtraction on the last digits of the numbers supplied and decimal subtraction on the rest.  I left the parameters and the return type as doubles but it would make more sense to have them as integers, since that's what they basically are.